# session does not keep the values

Tags: php, session, pagination

I have an array of variables and I need to show its values.

So at first I send "me" variable to copy the array into session then I send "mypage" variable to show the first variable of the array but when I send "mypage" variable it seems the session is empty as show function does not show anything.

Please advice if you think I should use any other method as I am doing this to implement pagination.

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_GET["me"])      //if me variable is received copy the array in session
{
   $myarray = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");
   $_SESSION["mysession"] = $myarray;
}

if(isset($_GET["mypage"])   // if mypage variable is received go to show function
   show()

show()   // show value 1 of the session
{
 $values = array();
 $values= $_SESSION['mysession'];
 echo $values[1];
}
```

?>

Comment: Where have you defined $_SESSION['values'] ?

Comment: Besides anything else, you ignore the return value of `session_start`. Why? This is unwise.

Comment: you used two sessions with two names: $_SESSION["mysession"] and $_SESSION['values'], should be like that or same name?

Comment: If you mean `$values= $_SESSION['mysession'];` instead of `$values= $_SESSION['values'];` here is the error

Comment: what are your suggestions I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very vague though for your question it seems that you are accessing SESSION with wrong key.

As you are setting session with `mysession` key above. Try to change below in your show function,

```
$values= $_SESSION['mysession'];
```

Comment: I changed it but does not work yet, it does not show anything.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SESSION['mysession']);`

Comment: previously it showed nothing but when I have used it showed NULL